# Software mutex with incoherent caches in dual-core system

Tags: multithreading, caching, concurrency, mutex

Suppose we have a system with 2 CPUs (without Out-of-order execution), each having a cache and an access to a shared memory. Caches are incoherent, but can be flushed by a request from the CPU. Also, concurrent flushes shall be avoided. 
Will a software mutex implementation, like a Dekker's algorithm work in such a configuration?
I suspect this is a circular problem, as maintaining cache coherency manually in software requires mutexes and implementing software mutexes requires cache coherency :)

Comment: You have to start by having some synchronization function or primitive. It's not clear what you're starting with. I guess explicit cache flushes?

Comment: Like I've said, you can explicitly flush cache, but you are not allowed to do that concurrently -> you need to synchronize -> can't implement a software synchronization :) I've asked the question only to be sure that I am not missing something.

Comment: It seems like Dekker's algorithm would be about the only thing that would work. You just need to sync both before and after you change something that tells other threads to look at something else.